# ion-select / ion-label not displayed properly with attribute floating in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

When using dynamic values for ion-select-choice, the ion-select label does not display correctly, both the value and the label are displayed on top of each other, see following picture.

[Click here to see a screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eETf9.png)

An example of code is available here on github: [Ionic 4 Ion-Select example](https://github.com/eltoky/tstSelect)

Here is a code excerpt of how ion-select is used and failing:

```
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Event Game</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="tstObj.key" (ionChange)="onChangeVal()">
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let game of gameLst" [value]="game.key">{{game.value}}</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

The data for the ion-select-choice are retrieved like that:

```
this.http.get('./assets/data.json').subscribe( (settings: any) => {
  this.gameLst = settings.gameLst;
});
```

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong to have this issue?

Here is the output of ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.6 (/Users/x/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.802.2
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.17
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.17
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 1.3.0
   @capacitor/core : 1.3.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.7 (update available: 0.2.9)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (/Users/x/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.13.0
   OS     : macOS Mojave
   Xcode  : Xcode 11.2.1 Build version 11B500
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="tstObj.key" (ionChange)="onChangeVal()">
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let game of gameLst" [value]="game.key">{{game.value}}</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
```

to this

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="game" (ionChange)="onChangeVal()">
            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let game of gameLst" [value]="game.key">{{game.value}}</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
```

also in your gamelst add a **selected** key like this

add this line

```
 for(let i=0;i<this.gameLst2.length;i++){
     this.gameLst2[i].selected = "false"
}
```

now for testing purpose lets make **selected ="true"** for any object

```
 this.gameLst2[2].selected = "true"
    console.log(this.gameLst2)
```

now we can select dynamically like this

```
<ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">Event Game</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="game" (ionChange)="onValChange()">
                <ion-select-option *ngFor="let game of gameLst2" [selected]="game.selected" [value]="game.key">{{game.value}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forked your project, and at least for me, the pre-selected value didn't even show until I clicked the select, where the default value show and problem you describe happened instantly before changing the value. I was managed to solve this by adding `selectedText` to the ion-select, like described [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-ion-select-pre-select-value/157025/3). That way the pre-selected value shows and the label is floated like expected.

So, try:

```html
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="tstObj.key" (ionChange)="onChangeVal()" [selectedText]="tstObj.key">
```